# Parsing an XML file with tags inside some values in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

First, thank you for your time, i need to to write a c# code that gets an XML response from a REST web service, some tags contain a special field with an entire tag inside the value here is an example :

```
<Root date="22.22.2222" version="specific system versonning">
<record field1="value1"  field2="value1" specialfield="just_a_normal_value"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2"value2" specialfield=" <multiplesubfields subfield1= "subvalue1" subfield2="subvalue2"/> " field3="value3"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2"value2" specialfield=" <multiplesubfields subfield1= "subvalue1" subfield2="subvalue2" subfield3="subvalue3"/> " field3="value3"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2="value1" specialfield="just_a_normal_value"/>
</Root>
```

The number of inner fields inside the tag value is not fixed. 
For some records the specialfield contains just a normal value with no tags inside, in that case no modifications needed.

What i want to do is to retrieve those subfields and values and add them to the parent tag as they where normal fields and remove the field specialfield from it the result should be then as following :

```
<Root date="22.22.2222" version="specific system versonning">
<record field1="value1"  field2="value1" specialfield="just_a_normal_value"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2"value2" subfield1= "subvalue1" subfield2="subvalue2" field3="value3"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2"value2" subfield1= "subvalue1" subfield2="subvalue2" subfield3="subvalue3" field3="value3"/>
<record field1="value1"  field2="value1" specialfield="just_a_normal_value"/>
</Root>
```

Following is code to get the XML file:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "www.blablabla.."

        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD");
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        using (HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
       {
        xmlDoc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
       }
    }
```

The above code is working and is fetching perfectly the file, i checked it with

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 XmlTextWriter tx = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
 xmlDoc.WriteTo(tx);
 System.Console.Writeline(sw.ToString());
```

but i have no clue how to do the rest in a clean way.I read many other similar posts in Stackoverflow and other Sites but still not able able to get started. I mean i have some ugly String treatement ideas of my own that might work but i don't even dare to try them =).

Thanks you all for reading this post.

Comment: This is not well-formed XML so any attempt at trying to parse this with an XML parser that expects well-formed XML will fail. In particular the quotes inside the quotes is going to be a big showstopper. Please verify that this is the **actual** XML you're trying to parse, and that it hasn't fallen pray to being interpreted by something before posting it here. For instance, are the innermost quotes really some escape characters?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, i am 100% sure its is the format i am receiveing, and you are right thats i am not able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        var result = doc.Root.Descendants("record").Where(x => x.Attribute("specialfield") != null && x.Attribute("specialfield").Value.Contains("multiplesubfields"));

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            item.Attribute("specialfield").Remove();
        }
```

You can use `XDocument`, after that take all records nodes and search for attributes which `specifiedfield` contains the `multiplesubfields` string.

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ to Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693062.aspx) is handy tool for working with xml.

You can parse special xml(`<multiplesubfields>`) as `XElement` and add attributes of the parsed element to the parent `<record>`.

```
const string XMLSTART = " <multiplesubfields";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(yourResponseStream);

var specialsRecords =
    doc.Root
       .Descendants("record")
       .Where(rec => rec.Attribute("specialfield") != null)
       .Where(rec => rec.Attribute("specialfield").Value.StartsWith(XMLSTART));

foreach (var special in specialsRecords)
{
    var multiplesubfields = XElement.Parse(special.Attribute("specialfield").Value);
    foreach (var subField in multiplesubfields.Attributes())
    {
        special.Add(subField);
    }

    // Remove original attribute
    special.Attribute("specialfield").Remove();
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Comment: Hi Fabio,
Thanks for your help, i am so sorry but working with XML is totally new to me and i am not a c# expert neither,  so my question mya be silly and sorry if it is, after trying to adapt your code i have a compiling error in VS :

XmlGenerator does not exist in the current context
and under descendants("record").where    i also have a complile error message :
 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable ...

Comment: `Where` extension method is in `System.Linq`

Comment: And replace `XmlGenerator` (which was wrong copy/paste line) with your stream

Comment: Hi fabio, thanks a lot!, 
I have a runtime exception : 
System.Xml.Xml{"Root element is missing."}

Comment: Line : doc = XDocument.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());

Comment: @user3255004, it usually means that response doesn't contain valid xml

Comment: I am able to get a response via XmlDocument, but right it is not valid, what should i do?

Answer (score -1):

check the url below you can get sample xml study them and have an object form of it.
http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/

i had similar isues when i was integrating with zenith bank Nigeria limite soap api. they values aint consistent and i had to study the situation.
cheers